# mysqld is getting killed by own

Tags: mysql, server, centos

I don't know what process is killing it. I have zero experience in CentOS. First it was not starting using

`service mysqld start`

And showing error

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183:  7618 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe: line 183:  7675 Killed                  nohup /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

So I read somewhere to run the following command

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Then mysqld starts normally, but within 10-15 seconds it again shows the error mentioned above. I think some process is killing it forcibly.

Here is mysqld.log

```
Version: '5.6.38'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-11-14 12:02:07 1535 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

And command `free -m` showing the output below in case it is helpful.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           512        280        231        128          0          7
-/+ buffers/cache:        272        239
Swap:          256        207         48
```

Below is my `my.cnf` file.

```
[mysqld]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql

thread_cache_size=4

join_buffer_size=4M
sort_buffer_size=4M
read_buffer_size=4M
read_rnd_buffer_size=6M

myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M

key_buffer_size=128M
tmp_table_size=128M
max_heap_table_size=128M
query_cache_size=256M

query_cache_type=1
default-storage-engine=myisam
#skip-innodb



[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**What can be the cause of that error and killing of mysqld and How can I resolve this?**

Comment: Have you tried to open log to see what's happening?

Comment: Looks like a memory issue... check to see if you're running out of memory for mysql/mariadb. see [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mariadb-process-getting-killed-once-a-day-on-fresh-centos-7-install)

Comment: First, it was starting after getting close, but now it is not even starting when 50% of MB RAM is free. Looks like some other process is killing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found that the problem was the lack of physical main memory.

> Increasing the main memory fixed my issue.